# Customize Quantity Selector in WooCommerce Cart

Tags: woocommerce, cart

I am using the Canvas theme from WooThemes, and running the WooCommerce plugin for my e-commerce website. My products are measured in Square Feet, and the order quantities range widely with random numbers of sq. ft. ordered.

The units of measure available to me in the WooCommerce cart do not include sq. ft., and the quantity selector only contains pre-selected quantities that range from 1 through 9.

How can I change the unit of measure to show sq. ft. and the quantity amount in the cart / check-out to be input manually as random numbers? For example: 1253 sq. ft.

https://prettyhardwoodflooring.com

Thanks,
Gene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of WooCommerce, Quantity field is set to [Number](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) input type. That's the reason for it.

Below is the screenshot taken from your site.

[image]

If you notice in that screenshot, number is set in **type**. So you need to change it to **text** in context of your desire result.

`<input name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" type="text">`

Replace it with above code and there you GO :)

Tell me if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thank you so much for the speedy reply! Could you also tell me where this folder is located, and direct me to some instruction on how to change it? Thanks!

Comment: Can't sure because it depends on your theme. If the theme that you are using have not done customization on it, then it will be located here `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\global\quantity-input.php`.

Comment: You can upvote it or even accept my answer. Glad that I can help you.

Comment: I made the change you suggested and it works awesome except for one thing. Only 3 digits show up in the little Qty. box where the numbers are typed in. For example: If a customer types in 1000, only 000 is visible in the box. I need to enlarge the Qty. box to show at least 5 digits. Thanks again so much for your help!

Comment: add `.quantity .qty{width:4.8em !important;}` to your CSS so it will show upto 6 digit. You can accept my answer if it helps you.